# richtext to byte[] and byte[] to richtext in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, arrays

How to convert `richtextbox` Text to byte[] and then again convert it to `richtextbox` text.
**Note:** `richtextbox` contain rich text including bold, italic, underline, different colors, various fontfamilies as well as different fontsize.
I am sending that byte[] over tcp by using this code

**Sending `Richtext` to server**

```
NetworkStream serverStream = default(NetworkStream);
byte[] outStream = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(rtb_UserMessage.text() + "$");
serverStream.Write(outStream, 0, outStream.Length);
```

**Receiving `Richtext` from server**

```
serverStream = clientSocket.GetStream();
int buffSize = 0;
byte[] inStream = new byte[10025];
buffSize = clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize;
serverStream.Read(inStream, 0, buffSize);
string returndata = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(inStream);
```

This code sending and receiving data but problem is the data lost all the Richtext format

**Edit:** That duplicate question just solved my 1st part. How to reconvert Plaintext to RTF so that the `RichTextBox` can show the Rich Text. The plaintext is look like this

```
 {\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\uc1\htmautsp\deff2{\fonttbl{\f0\fcharset0 Times New Roman;}{\f2\fcharset0 Segoe UI;}{\f3\fcharset0 Blackadder ITC;}}{\colortbl\red0\green0\blue0;\red255\green255\blue255;}\loch\hich\dbch\pard\plain\ltrpar\itap0{\lang1033\fs21\f2\cf0 \cf0\ql\sl20\slmult0{\fs108\f3 {\ltrch uzair}\li0\ri0\sa0\sb0\fi0\ql\sl20\slmult0\par}
}
}{\rtf1\ansi{\fonttbl\f0\fswiss Helvetica;}\f0\pard \{\\rtf1\\ansi\\ansicpg1252\\uc1\\htmautsp\\deff2\{\\fonttbl\{\\f0\\fcharset0 Times New Roman;\}\{\\f2\\fcharset0 Segoe UI;\}\{\\f3\\fcharset0 Blackadder ITC;\}\}\{\\colortbl\\red0\\green0\\blue0;\\red255\\green255\\blue255;\}\\loch\\hich\\dbch\\pard\\plain\\ltrpar\\itap0\{\\lang1033\\fs21\\f2\\cf0 \\cf0\\ql\\sl20\\slmult0\{\\fs108\\f3 \{\\ltrch uzair\}\\li0\\ri0\\sa0\\sb0\\fi0\\ql\\sl20\\slmult0\\par\} \par \} \par \} }
```

Comment: That answer converting richtext to xml format should I convert richtext to xml and if yes then how to reconvert that xml to richtext?

Comment: Use `DataFormats.Rtf` instead of `DataFormats.Xaml`

Comment: Ok but how to reconvert that plantext to rtf